# Postgres mounting volume in docker. Permission denied

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I try to mapping folder on the host to postgres container in order to save my data even if container destroy.

Firstly I created new directory pg-data

[image]

Secondly I describe container in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  backend-network:
    driver: bridge
  frontend-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
   redis-data:
   pg-data:

services:
  &app-service app: &app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_app
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
      args:
        UID: ${UID?Use your user ID}
        GID: ${GID?Use your group ID}
        USER: ${USER?Use your user name}
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    hostname: *app-service
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd/:/etc/passwd:ro
      - /etc/group/:/etc/group:ro
      - ./:/var/www/k4fntr
    environment:
      APP_ENV: "${APP_ENV}"
      CONTAINER_ROLE: app
      FPM_PORT: &php-fpm-port 9000
      FPM_USER: "${UID:-1000}"
      FPM_GROUP: "${GID:-1000}"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - database
    networks:
      - backend-network

  &queue-service queue:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_queue
    restart: always
    hostname: *queue-service
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: queue

  &schedule-service schedule:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_schedule
    restart: always
    hostname: *schedule-service
    depends_on:
      - app
    environment:
      CONTAINER_ROLE: scheduler

  &php-fpm-service php-fpm:
    <<: *app-service-template
    container_name: k4fntr_php-fpm
    user: 'root:root'
    restart: always
    hostname: *php-fpm-service
    ports: [*php-fpm-port]
    entrypoint: /fpm-entrypoint.sh
    command: php-fpm --nodaemonize -d "opcache.enable=0" -d "display_startup_errors=On" -d "display_errors=On" -d "error_reporting=E_ALL"
    networks:
      - backend-network
      - frontend-network

  mail:
    container_name: k4fntr_mail
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
    - "1025:1025"
    - "8025:8025"
      - backend-network

  database:
    container_name: k4fntr_database
    build: ./docker/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/prod/:/prod
      - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
    networks:
      - backend-network

    - backend-network

  database:
    container_name: k4fntr_database
    build: ./docker/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/prod/:/prod
      - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    networks:
      - backend-network

    - backend-network

  nginx:
    container_name: k4fntr_nginx
    image: nginx
    volumes:
    - ./docker/nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./:/var/www/k4fntr
    depends_on:
      - *php-fpm-service
    ports:
      - "8084:80"
    networks:
      - frontend-network

  redis:
    container_name: k4fntr_redis
    image: redis
    restart: always
    command: redis-server
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis/config/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - ./docker/redis/redis-data:/data:rw
    ports:
     - "16379:6379"
    networks:
      - backend-network

  database:
    container_name: k4fntr_database
    build: ./docker/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      ENV: ${APP_ENV}
      TESTING_DB: ${DB_DATABASE_TESTING}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DB_DATABASE}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/prod/:/prod
      - ./docker/postgres/pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

I also have Dockerfile in docker/postgres/ which is contains the next code

```
    FROM postgres:10.5-alpine

    COPY /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

    RUN apk add openssh-client
    RUN chmod a+r /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

    RUN mkdir /prod

    RUN chmod a+r /prod
```

Then I build my image with docker-compose exec -d --build

After it my user changes on 70:root

[image]

and I can't doing any with this folder without sudo. Also when I try to rebuild the container I got an error

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose up -d --build
Building database
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 72, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 128, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1077, in up
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 1073, in up
  File "compose/project.py", line 548, in up
  File "compose/service.py", line 351, in ensure_image_exists
  File "compose/service.py", line 1106, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 160, in build
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 30, in tar
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 49, in exclude_paths
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 214, in rec_walk
  File "site-packages/docker/utils/build.py", line 184, in rec_walk
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ubuntu/PhpstormProjects/fntr/docker/postgres/pg-data'
[16332] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

And I need to remove this folder (with sudo) and then do rebuild.

What I tried:

1 - I have read the instruction from https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres (Arbitrary --user Notes) and tried to volume /etc/passwd inside the container and user: "${UID}:${GID}", but got an error

```
initdb: could not access directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data": permission denied
```

2 - use PGDATA into another place and got the same error with rebuild

3 - create /var/lib/postgresql/data in Dockerfile with 777 permissions, but postgres entrypoints from image just removed this folder and recreated it

I really need help with this issue because I spent 3 days without effect

Comment: To immediately solve the docker-compose up --build problem, add the pg-data directory to the .dockerignore file for the project.  This issue is discussed on [github](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/392#issuecomment-408110910)

Answer (score 8):

This is what have worked for me on manjaro linux.

First I need to manually create pgdata folder. If I omit this step, docker will create pgdata with the wrong permission.

```
mkdir -p /some/path/pddata
```

Next I create the docker container and map my user with the --user argument:

```
docker container run -d --name=pg -p 5432:5432 --user $(id -u):$(id -g) -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e PGDATA=/pgdata -v /host/path/to/pgdata:/pgdata postgres:latest
```

Comment: thank you. after a lot of test and tries. your solutions works

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me, perhaps you need to start with a simpler set up that works and find out what causes a problem as you move towards your complete config:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

volumes:
   pg-data:

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGDATA: /pg-data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pg-data:/pg-data
```

So ...

```
########################################
# start db
########################################
▶ docker-compose up -d
Creating docker-compose-pg_database_1 ... done

########################################
# note pg-data is created
########################################
▶ ls
docker-compose.yml pg-data

########################################
# create some data
########################################
▶ docker-compose exec database psql -U postgres
psql (12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create database foo;
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# \q

########################################
# remove the container and any non-mounted data
########################################
▶ docker-compose rm -sf
Stopping docker-compose-pg_database_1 ... done
Going to remove docker-compose-pg_database_1
Removing docker-compose-pg_database_1 ... done

########################################
# start the container again
########################################
▶ docker-compose up -d
Creating docker-compose-pg_database_1 ... done

########################################
# see data from before
########################################
▶ docker-compose exec database psql -U postgres
psql (12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 foo       | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the ownership off all files in the Postgres' Docker volume back to be owned by the containers postgres user.

```bash
docker compose run --rm --user root <service-name> chown -R postgres:postgres /home/postgres/pgdata/
```

**Alternatively**

Another way to do it is to find the user and group id for the postgres user in the container,

```bash
> docker compose exec timescale id -u
1000
> docker compose exec timescale id -g
1000
```

And then set change the ownership of the files from the Docker host to the user id and group id the containers postgres users belongs to.

```bash
chown -R 1000:1000 /var/lib/docker/volumes/<postgres-data-volume-name>
```